# HP Fanfic where Sirius is in a relationship with a healer named Sebastian and they take custody of Harry

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, sirius-black

I remember several details about this story:

Sirius is gay, I believe his boyfriend was named Sebastian.

At one point his boyfriend (Sebastian) was called in because it turned out Ron's body had been greatly damaged by smallpox as a child, and his magic had taken over several organ's functions completely and that's why he was a relatively weak wizard.

At one point Sirius is cursed by Dumbledore (or on his orders I'm not entirely sure) inside 12 Grimmauld Place, although no one realized it was him until later on. Dumbledore did this to get Harry out of his custody, but Sirius prevented it by naming Sebastian as his guardian if something happened.

I read this about 2 years ago I think. It was on fanfiction.net

Comment: Why did you delete [the same question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221101/harry-potter-fanfic-where-sirius-takes-custody-of-harry) and ask it again?

Comment: If you know where it was, why do you ask here?

Comment: Because I accidentally removed it when I signed up for an account. I didn't know I could undelete it. Also, I know where it was, but I don't know what *story* it was, hence why I asked. This is not a very friendly community for newcomers is it? Sorry I didn't understand the rules at first

Comment: @JamesAndrews: There are some ways to attempt to manipulate the system via multiple accounts. People are a bit wary of that.

Comment: @JamesAndrews It's a community that is protective of the standards for its posts. It doesn't take long for new users to appreciate this. But it can initially come off as unfriendly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LMGTFY: Pretty drecky, but I think you're looking for *[Doing Things Differently](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10508602/1/Doing-Things-Differently)*.

> Ch. 8: Sebastian and Harry are conversing...
>
> "Come now, Harry.  I'm sure you figured it out already.  Sirius and I are lovers."  He said this calmly but Harry freaked out.